# Grouping by same column / variable using two separate imported views and separate calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So basically my code involves a created a table which has the LAST COLUMN as the SUM of the previous two columns, with the first of the two coming from table X and the second of the two columns coming from the 'INNER JOIN OF table X with table Y'.

HOWEVER, I want to group ALL THREE of these columns by the 'COUNTERPARTY', a variable which is present BOTH in 'table X' AND in 'INNER JOIN OF TABLE X WITH TABLE Y.'

The tricky part is that there will be some COUNTERPARTIES for which we have data set 1 (coming from TABLE X) and some COUNTERPARTIES for which we have data set 2 (coming from INNER JOIN OF table X with table Y) and SOME FOR WHICH WE HAVE BOTH DATASETS! I WANT TO INCLUDE THE INTERSECTION AS WELL AS THE OUTLIERS BUT ONLY AFTER CHECKED AGAINST A MASTER KEY OF COUNTERPARTIES called c.COUNTERPTY.

Please carefully go through the code below to see how the above explanation is relevant to the problem at hand. I apologize for the length of the code.

```
select 
p.Name as ENTITY, t.[Counterparty Code],  c.CNTRPTY_DS as COUNTERPARTY, cs.Tier,

... irrelevant code removed

sum((t.[Current value decimal] - t.[Trade price decimal])/100 * case when t.[Buy Sell Code] = 'B' 
then  1 else -1 end * t.[Open Amount]) as [OPEN MTM ($)],

sum((t2.[Weighted Average Settled Pair Off Price] - t2.[Trade price decimal])/100 * case when t2.[Buy Sell Code] = 'B' 
then  1 else -1 end * ISNULL(PO.[Pairoff Amount],0)) as [Unsettled Pairoffs/ AOTs ($)],

sum((t.[Current value decimal] - t.[Trade price decimal])/100 * case when t.[Buy Sell Code] = 'B' 
then  1 else -1 end * t.[Open Amount]) + sum((t2.[Weighted Average Settled Pair Off Price] - t2.[Trade price decimal])/100 * case when t2.[Buy Sell Code] = 'B' 
then  1 else -1 end * ISNULL(PO.[Pairoff Amount],0)) as [TOTAL MTM Exposure ($)]

from
[la-w08-qrm-db-1].qrmprod.dbo.vw_QRM_Trades t2
inner join 
[la-w08-qrm-db-1].qrmprod.dbo.VW_QRM_TRADE_PAIROFFS PO 
ON 
PO.[In Ticket Number] = t2.[Ticket number] 
and PO.[Portfolio ID] = t2.[Portfolio ID]
and t2.[derivative type] = 'F'                      -- note repeat below
and t2.[forward type] ='MBS'                        
and t2.[Counterparty Code] not in ('PLS', 'PNCO')
and t2.[Portfolio ID] in  (1,7)
and t2.[Settlement date] > GETDATE(),

prod.dbo.vw_QRM_Trades t,
prod.dbo.portdesc p,
prod.dbo.cptyall c, 
prod.dbo.VW_MB_ACTIVE_RUN r,
pulsar.dbo.CntrPrtySetup CS,
pulsar.dbo.CntrPrtyTiers CT
where
 r.mrktid =  1 
 And r.asmpid =  1 
 And r.cyclid =  1
 and r.compid = t.[Company ID]  
 and r.portid = t.[Portfolio ID]
 and p.PORTID = t.[Portfolio ID]
 and c.COUNTERPTY = t.[Counterparty Code] --key piece of code
 and cs.CNTRPTY_NO = c.CNTRPTY_NO
 and cs.PortID = t.[Portfolio ID]
 and cs.Tier = ct.Tier
 and t.[derivative type] = 'F'                   -- note repeat above
 and t.[forward type] ='MBS'
 and t.[Counterparty Code] not in ('PLS', 'PNCO')
 and t.[Portfolio ID] in  (1,7)
 and t.[Open Amount] > 0
 group by
 p.Name,  c.CNTRPTY_DS , t.[Counterparty Code], cs.Tier  -- yes this
 order by
 p.Name,  c.CNTRPTY_DS , t.[Counterparty Code], cs.Tier   -- and this
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you show some example data and the expected result...?

Comment: I need 4 more reputation points to post an image of the output :(

Comment: Your description of what you want to end up with is confusing. If you are inner joining tables X and Y, you shouldn't end up with counterparties not in table X (unless counterparty is in table Y AND not included in the join). Also if you want rows that are in table X but not in the join in your result set, then why are you inner joining rather than left joining?

Clarify what data you need to your result set and where in tables X and Y that data is located.

Comment: So the rows which each represent one counterparty per row, should be all the counterparties for which there is OPEN MTM ($) != 0 AND/OR Unsettled Pairoffs/ AOTs ($) != 0. Yes there IS a case where the counterparty would not show up with just Table X, if there is no data for it in table X BUT JUST THE NAME, and THERE IS data for that NAME in Table Y, table X contains the names of the counterparties AND data used to compute Open MTM.

Comment: Table Y contains some data to compute Pairoff MTM and the rest of the data is actually in table X. However, a counterparty could have either one of the two, both, or neither, and I want to see the counterparty listed when either exists and also when both exist (By both Open MTM and Pairoff MTM).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way to do is was to actually use UNION in order to join three tables together in the order and given the properties I wanted from each of them. Eventually I did manage to finish the whole stored procedure!